# Biblatex - capital names in references, regular in cites

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

I am trying to achieve a biblatex style that would do the following:

in the case of `\parencite{}` I would get `...like that (Smith 2010).`

in the case of `\textcite{}` I would get `Smith (2010) says that...`

but in References I would get `SMITH, J. Bookname.`

How can I achieve this?

I use `\usepackage[style=authoryear, firstinits=true]{biblatex}`

I tried `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` but that makes the name uppercase even in the text, which is undesirable especially with `\textcite{}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the macro just for the bibliography and `biblatex` provides a hook to do this in the form of `\AtBeginBibliography`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Here is some text \parencite{angenendt}. Note that \textcite{angenendt} mentions something.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Capitalised last names in bibliography only]

---

**EDIT**

Current versions of `biblatex` have a slightly different naming scheme, for them the code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\begin{document}
Here is some text \parencite{angenendt}. Note that \textcite{angenendt} mentions something.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr Please feel free to undo my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @samcarter Not at all. Thanks for adding the code to work with the update. I'd not remembered I answered a question which would be affected by the changes to Biblatex or I'd have updated it myself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to do something similar to embolden names in the references while keeping them regular in citations?