# Citation: How to set up lower case in partial citation and upper case in full reference for the author names?

Tags: biblatex, citing

**Note**: My english isn't that good. My native english is german. I don't know the correct definition of german *wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung*, which I called here as *academic writing*, german *Kurzbeleg*, which is the short reference in a citation in a continuous text, which I called here as *partial citation* and german *Langbeleg*, which is the full entry in the bibliography at the end of the written work, which I called here as *full reference*. I also couldn't find a correct translation of this definitions. So I someone has the experience with it, so please edit this question in the correct manner. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you!

For my academic writing I have to set the names of the authors like this example:

1. Partial citation: (Surname, Name 2000, S. 1)
2. Full reference: SURNAME, NAME, 2000. Title...

Code for above example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            babel,
            csquotes
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nty,
            style = authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{
        Sur,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        title  = {Title},
        year   = {2000},
       }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Test \autocite[1]{Sur}.
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this task?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: Regarding the terminology: The format of what you call 'partial citation' is determined by the citation style you use, while the format of the 'full reference'  is controlled by the bibliography style.

Comment: If you are more comfortable asking questions in German you can try https://texwelt.de/ a German-language Q&A site similar to TeX.SX or https://golatex.de/ a classical forum. But as far as I am concerned your questions are understandable.

Comment: Just so this gets commented in the right place: Below https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438509/35864 leandriis linked to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154923/134144. And I suggested `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}`

Comment: Hello leandriis and @moewe! Thank you both for your comments! I edited my question to be consequent with my following question. @moewe I know about this german sites. I'am here because here is more support and more information and I learn english.

Comment: Did the suggested solution work for you?

Comment: Hello @moewe! Thank you for your comment! Yes it works for me, thank you!