# Citation: How to fine tune the full reference?

Tags: biblatex, citing

This question continous my [other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438507/citation-how-to-set-up-lower-case-in-partial-citation-and-upper-case-in-full-re).

**Note**: My english isn't that good. My native english is german. I don't know the correct definition of german *wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung*, which I called here as *academic writing* and german *Langbeleg*, which is the full entry in the bibliography at the end of the written work, which I called here as *full reference*. I also couldn't find a correct translation of this definitions. So I someone has the experience with it, so please edit this question in the correct manner. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you!

1. The parentheses `()` around the year in the full reference of my academic writing are not allowed.
2. In front of the year should be a comma, like this example:

Full reference: SURNAME, NAME, 2000. Title...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            babel,
            csquotes
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nty,
            style = authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{
        Sur,
        author = {Surname, Name},
        title  = {Title},
        year   = {2000},
       }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Test \autocite[1]{Sur}.
  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

How can I implement this things?

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: The requirements in this question seem to contradict the requirements in your previous question. In your previous question, your example of what the output should look like contains no comma between name and year and has parentheses around the year.

Comment: Regarding the capitalization of names only in the bibliography you might want to have a look at the following question: [Biblatex - capital names in references, regular in cites](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154923/134144)

Comment: But please don't use `\MakeUppercase`, do yourself and your readers a favour and use `\textsc`: `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}`

Comment: You'll want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864

Comment: Hello @leandriis! Thank you for your comment! My intention was to split my questions due to _one thing - one question_ principle of TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange (aka don't ask too much things per time). But your comment shows, that something goes wrong. I edited my first question to be consequent.

Comment: Did the linked question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428190/35864 help?

Comment: Hello @moewe! Thank you for your comment! Yes it helped, thank you!